# Financial calculations without floating point numbers in console?

Tags: command-line, calculator

I need to do simple financial calculations on Linux and had been using `wcalc` for this until I stumbled upon a wrong result caused by floating-point number issues. Is there a calculator (I really would prefer the command-line) that one can rely on for this task? One that doesn't use floats internally?

Comment: What kind of operations must the calculator support? There's always `bc`, which is an arbitrary-precision arithmetic calculator.

Comment: Nothing special. Bc looks promising, but wcalc also calls itself an "arbitrary-precision calculator", But for wcalc, I could not find a statement like bc's "All numbers are represented internally in decimal and all computation is done in decimal"

Comment: I haven't looked at the `bc` source code to see what it's doing, but "decimal" is not the same as "integer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments to my question, `bc` doesn't have this problem. Another solution is the the more powerful command line of [`Qalculate!`](https://qalculate.github.io/) which seems to fulfill my needs.